# Add ints but choose the one closest to the number I want

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm sitting here and trying to do this task.
(https://open.kattis.com/problems/walrusweights)

> The first input contains the number of plates I should use (ints).
>   The ints after are the plates (weights) and each of them should be <= than 1000.
>   Add the ints together and try come so close to 1000 as possible, BUT
>   in case there exist two such numbers which are equally close to 1000, (998 and 1002) then choose the greater one.

Say that I have 4 plates, the first one is 4, 900, 500, 498.
Adding them so you come close as possible to 1000.
498+500 = 998.
500+498+4= 1002.
In this case, choose the 1002.

```
int sum=0;
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 int count = scan.next();
 for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
   sum = sum + scan.next();
 }
```

or

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = scan.nextInt();

while(count > 0) {
//your logic
count--;
}
```

I have tried but don't understand the logic/algorithm of how to compare the added numbers and if they are equal, choose the greater one.
All I get is that I can put in the counter and the weights and it will add it up, can someone explain how to make the algorithm? What should I read to understand this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you know anything about dynamic programming before?

Comment: I'm sitting here with three Java books and trying to understand Algorithms and how it works, have read 2 of them, but nothing about dynamic programming.        Have you any good advice/books, sites? Would appreciate that, thank you.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/) or [this](https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-dynamic-programming)

Comment: Isn't 1000 closer to 1000 than 990 or 1010 is? Why isn't answer `500+500` or `10+490+500`? Both are closer to 1000 that your listed choices of `490+500` or `500+500+10`.

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry for that, it was an example to show the equality between 2 numbers when one is under 1000 and the other over 1000, can change it if you want to :)

Comment: Thanks again  Pham Trung for the links :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a dynamic programming problem and this is the first thing to Google if you are not familiar with this approach. The idea in this task is to create an array `A` of size 2001 (note that any possible answer is less than or equal to 2000). Initially, `A[0] = true` and for all other indices `A[i] = false`. Then, for each plate you iterate from 1000 down to 0 and if `A[i] == true` then `A[i + currentWeight] = true`. This way you compute which overall weights are possible to get with your plates. At the end you find the index `x` such that `A[x] == true` and `(x - 1000)` is as small as possible (in case of draw you take the largest such `x`).

Comment: Thank you so much. Think you meant 1000 and not 2000, but thanks again, will google it and read about dynamic programming and how to use arrays in this way.

Comment: Thanks, you can iterate from 1000 down to 0 but your array should have size greater than 1000 because possible solution can exceed 1000, as in the example dataset in the task.

Comment: Since array will likely be sparse, i.e. only a few values will be true, searching for the true values will be slow. A better performing solution could use a `TreeMap` or a sorted array.

Comment: I think it depends on the number of plates. In the task it's up to 1000 so with a small weights range they can quickly fill A with true values. Pessimistic time complexity can't be reduced below O(n * w) where w is weight range. When I see such algorithmic tasks I usually think about the pessimistic case in Big O notation.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ardavel suggests, this is called dynamic programming.
One famous problem is the [*Knapsack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem, another is *[Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)*'s algorithm for the shortest path problem.

The basic idea behind this approach is to break to sub-tasks and store the sub-results. 
You solve each sub-task once and store their solutions in a lookup.
The next time the same subproblem occurs, instead of recomputing its solution, you use the lookup and save time and memory.
In your case you sum sub-elements in a similar matter to the Knapsack problem.